# Getting connected to VPN but other sites not opening

Tags: vpn, connection

I am on 10.10 and have been able to get connected to a VPN server. But the problem is I can't open any other sites when I am connected to VPN.

It's working in Win though, where I was able to browse any sites and the VPN site at the same time without issues.

Must be I am missing something here. Please help.

Comment: Run "route" command before and after connecting to VPN and add its output to question. I guess that when you connect to VPN a default route gets added which redirects all the traffic over VPN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now.

I had not entered the Domain info.

Comment: @Arindom: Press the [v] on the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks Lekensteyn. I tried but it says "You can't vote for your own post". As per I understand instead of commenting to the actual answer, I had mistakenly answered on my own question. That is why it is not working. Please advise if you want me to do anything else to close this question.

Comment: @Arindom: I see the problem, you've two accounts. Request an account merge at http://meta.askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks Lekensteyn. I have requested here : http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1328/please-merge-my-two-accounts

Comment: @Lekensteyn : I have now accepted the answer. Hope that is correct. Please suggest if I need to take any further steps with regard to this question.

Comment: @Arindom: you could expand your answer, is Domain info the gateway?

Comment: @Lekensteyn : I have now asked a similar type question with more details already.